# Git Bash in Windows requires .exe extension for some but not all programs

Tags: windows, bash

I have my `$PATH` variable pointed at the location of `MSBuild.exe`.  If I type `MSBuild.exe`, it runs fine, but if I leave off the `.exe`, it can't find it.  However, I can type `ssh-add` or `notepad` and it runs fine without the extension.  The same goes for running `which` against those names.

First, why?
Second, how do I change it so I can leave off `.exe` when running `MSBuild`?  (I'd rather not define an alias in `.bashrc`.)

Best guess: Git Bash (or MINGW64 or whatever) creates extension-less links (symbolic or hard) to common executables like notepad and command prompt in places it knows are in `$PATH`.  I came to this by noting that `which notepad` returns a path in `/usr/bin` while `which notepad.exe` returns the Windows path, but this is just a guess.  Evidence to the contrary is that `ls -al /usr/bin/ssh-add*` only returns the `.exe` path.

**Note**: `$PATHEXT` includes `.EXE`

```
$ echo $PATHEXT
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior, as the Windows environment has no meaning in WSL.
CMD and PowerShell do not implicitly call anything in WSL
(`/usr/bin/` etc.).
Vice verso, neither CMD nor PowerShell understand Linux shebangs.

For example, it would be a major inconvenience if in bash, when calling `python`,
it by default called the windows `python.exe` binary instead of the Linux one.

This was the subject for the WSL bug-report, refused by Microsoft
[obviate typing the filename extension for Windows executables](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2003).

However, the following code was contributed by a user that can do what you ask.
Place it in your `~/.bashrc` if you want to take the above risk of confusing
Windows and Linux executables:

```
eval "$(echo "orig_command_not_found_handle()"; declare -f command_not_found_handle | tail -n +2)"
command_not_found_handle()
{
   cmd=$1
   shift
   args=( "$@" )

   IFS=:
   for dir in $PATH; do
      for executable in $dir/$cmd.exe $dir/$cmd.com $dir/$cmd.bat; do
         if [ -x $executable ]; then
            "$executable" "${args[@]}"
            return
         fi
      done
   done

   orig_command_not_found_handle "$cmd" "${args[@]}"
}
```

Comment: Does it matter that I'm not actually using WSL?  This is with Git Bash which basically just provides a bash shell over the WIndows filesystem.

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883760/git-for-windows-bashrc-or-equivalent-configuration-files-for-git-bash-shell) it should work the same. Read not only the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh, I don't doubt that it works.  I'm wondering, since I'm not actually running Linux, why there would be an inconvenience running the "linux" version of python.  Why does this error pop up in the first place?  And why can I run `ssh-add` which only exists as `/usr/bin/ssh-add.exe` but not msbuild?

Comment: The two pythons wouldn't be the same. Anyway, the Windows and Linux environments aren't totally integrated, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1497820/wsl-filesystem-miscoherency). It's possible that for some executables, such as `ssh-add` (if there is really no other such file), there are defined Linux shortcuts.

Comment: Git bash has ***nothing to do*** with WSL.  It is a stand alone Win32/Mingw-w64 (cygwin like) bash thingamajig that comes with git for windows.  The rules are ever stranger than they are with WSL.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: It's still a flavor of Linux under Windows. I don't use it, but according to the above links, my answer has a good chance of working the same. It's best tested by someone that has the environment.

Comment: @harrymc.. sure :)  worth a shot.  I use WSL/bash ***AND*** git bash.  They behave very differently when it comes to interoperability.. still worth a shot.

Comment: Does the downvote mean that it was tried by someone and didn't work? If so, please tell what happened.

Comment: The downvote was an accident which I will step up and own.. you are right about trying it first.  it won't let me take it back unless you edit the answer. :|  I suck.  I already tried to take it back before your reply.. I wish that rule would be changed.

Comment: I had to move the eval line down to the end.. otherwise, the rewritten "command_not_found_handle()" function isn't in scope and you get ***"bash: eval: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file"***.  Once I moved it to the end, the error went away and the function ended up in my environment.  I don't know if it actually works or not but it at least doesn't error out.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: No problem and thanks for testing. Answer edited. If you have a correction to the code, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding aliases for the handful of programs you frequently use in your `~/.bashrc` like so:

```sh
alias MSBuild=MSBuild.exe
alias kubectl=kubectl.exe
```